# Result set returning false even though data exists

Tags: java, jdbc

This is the code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {        
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","hr","root");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from mails");        
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(rs.next());
    }
```

I have a table named mails and it contains data. But the output i get when i run the above code is false.

I tried with other tables in my database. I got the output as true for every table but for mails table

Here is the table:-

```
mid      uname           fromid           subject        sentdate     content
------+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------------+-----------
1     to_srivatsav    abc@gmail.com     Mail1 Subject   10-JAN-17   Test Mail1 
2     to_srivatsav    xyz@gmail.com     Mail2 Subject   12-JAN-17   Test Mail2 
3     to_srivatsav    cg@gmail.com      Mail3 Subject   13-JAN-17   Test Mail2 
4     to_srivatsav    abcd@gmail.com    Mail4 Subject   14-JAN-17   Test Mail2
```

Help me out...!
thanks!

Comment: Which DB are you using ? try `select * from <schema-name>.mails`

Comment: I am using oracle db

Comment: no luck man..! :(

Comment: Tried it....still false  @YCF_L

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the right table? if you run the query in sqlplus do you get the result?

Comment: Just to get this out of the way. The records exist as of some time, you havent inserted them just now in a different connection without commiting the transaction right?

Comment: I got the output when i tried in the sql-editor. I am not getting the output using jdbc  @Juan

Comment: And you entered the data using the same sql-editor and didn't commit that transaction, right?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you @Tom but as you said I did enter the data using sql-editor

Comment: Just press the button that says commit in the editor and try again

Comment: Thanks man.!!! got it, but can you explain why this happened? @Juan

Comment: Just do research what a transaction is.

Comment: You are using transactions. The changes you do in a transaction are not visible to other connections until the transaction is committed. This gives you a chance to reverse all changes doing a rollback is something goes wrong when updating differeent tables in a an atomic way.

Comment: Sure....thanks a lot for responses..!! @Tom

Comment: got it :) @Juan